# How to substitute values ​in a component from two arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of houses that comes from Firestore, and an array of images of those houses that come from Storage. With the help of map, I go through the array of houses and supply information about it to the component. How do I iterate through an array of images and add them to a component?

```js
const List = ({ selectedHouse }) => {
  const [houseTitles, setHouseTitle] = useState([]);
  const [houseImages, setHouseImages] = useState([]);
  const imageListRef = ref(storage, "images/");
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setHouseTitle(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(imageListRef).then((response) => {
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          setHouseImages((prev) => [...prev, url]);
        });
      });
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="list-container" style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      <ListItem title={houseTitles[selectedHouse]?.data?.title} />
      {houseTitles
        .filter((title, index) => index !== selectedHouse)
        .map((title, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} title={title?.data?.title} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const ListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="list-item">
      <img src={props.url} alt="" />
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can put the code of the two `useEffect` hook calls in a single one since the dependency array is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you write some code for what it might look like?

Comment: Blocks of code are not well-formated when put in comments. You can just remove the lines that have `}, []);` and `useEffect(() => {` respectively. Please note that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you are looking for:

```
return (
  // ...
    {houseTitles
      .map((title, idx) => ({title, image: houseImages[idx]}))
      .filter((_houseArr, idx) => idx !== selectedHouse)
      .map((houseArr, idx) => (
        <ListItem key={idx} title={houseArr.title?.data?.title} url={/* YOUR IMAGE SRC HERE, IS IT houseArr.image? */} />
      ))}
  // ...
)
```